# QGIS 2.18 Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.18

I am using the Georeferencer plugin to overlay an older map over a OpenLayers google streetview map. I have set all my GCP points to be accurate however once I click the begin georeferencing button which should load my older map as a new vector layer only my red gcp points load and my map is no where to be found. Do you guys have any ideas as to how I can fix this? This is my first time posting here so if I left out important info feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Did you check the Coordinate Ref. System of layers? Try zooming to the extent of the new vector layer by right-clicking and using "Zoom to Layer".

Comment: Make sure the box is checked for "load in QGIS when done."